# How to fix ObjectDisposedException was Unhandled?

Tags: c#, error-handling

So I'm trying to write a simple code for educational purpose that takes a string from a textbox and writes it to txt file. Every time upon pressing the button for the second time I get this error message: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygsm1.png)

Here is the code:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("somefile.txt");
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string textBoxStuff = textBox1.Text;
                textBox1.Text = "";
                using (sw)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(textBoxStuff);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are explicitly telling it to close sw after the first time you press the button.

```
            using (sw)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(textBoxStuff);
            }
```

At the end of a using() statement, the object being used is disposed.  That's all a using statement really is, it's basically syntactic sugar around the following:

```
            try
            {
                sw.WriteLine(textBoxStuff);
            }
            finally
            {
                sw.Dispose();
            }
```

In this case, your variable sw stays in scope and is still available for the second button press, but your first button press has already closed the file when Dispose() was called.  If you really intend to keep the file open for the life of this form, you don't want to use `using` here, you want to dispose of the object at a more appropriate point.

The other option is not to hold the file open through the entire lifetime of your form, but open and close it each time you push the button.  In that case, you'd make a local streamwriter object and put it in a using statement.

Comment: What you would do is exactly what you're doing now, except get rid of the `using {` and the associated closing `}`.  You would also likely want to add a `sw.Dispose()` somewhere where you know that you no longer need the stream.

Comment: (I added an extra line of code to the question to complete the code that I have written)
If I do it that way it just simply doesn't write anything, and if I manually add 'sw.Dispose();' than I get the same problem at the second button press.

Comment: Don't add sw.Dispose() in the button press.  Add sw.Dispose() somewhere where you're sure you will never again need sw.  For example, you could add it in the Form's OnClosing() method when you know the button is being destroyed (and could never again be pushed).

Comment: But that way it doesn't write anything, it just creates an empty document and it leaves it that way.

Comment: As long as you are using sw.WriteLine(), it will (eventually) write the line to the file.  It may buffer the line in memory for an arbitrarily long time before flushing to disk.  If you want to force it to write immediately, then add `sw.Flush();` after the WriteLine to ensure the data is written immediately.  You can also set `sw.AutoFlush = true;` when you create the StreamWriter and this will flush data automatically after every write.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already called dispose on your StreamWriter somewhere else.

You can try this (using new instance that has not been disposed):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string textBoxStuff = textBox1.Text;
    textBox1.Text = "";
    using (var streamWriter = /*create your StreamWriter instance somehow*/)
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(textBoxStuff);
    }
}
```

As a rule of thumb I do not put any of the classes fields in an using block and I use it only on local method variables.
If for some reason you need IDispossable field and you need to keep it alive during all the classes lifetime, I make the class implement IDispossable and in the dispose method i call the dispsoe method of this field.

Answer (score 0):

check that the textwriter refer to a valid file :

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("C:\\perl.txt")) // Check the file here
    {

        writer.WriteLine("First line");

    }
```

or

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.AppendText(path)) // Check the file here
    {

        writer.WriteLine("First line");

    }
```

Comment: can probebly change the method of calling

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message when trying to show a form that was closed.

Here's how I got around the problem;

```cs
if (myForm.IsDisposed)
            myForm = new Form();
myForm.Show();
```